# Package naming and compatibility for Linux system

Tags: compiling, compatibility, software-distribution

I have library built as a .so file. I compiled in my Fedora 22.

The release of OS is.

```
$ uname -r
4.2.6-200.fc22.x86_64
```

for example if my library name is 'libfoo.so', how should I properly name it to show the system compatibility of the package?

I have another system running Fedora 22 with different release number  `4.2.3-200.fc22.x86_64`. If I intended to run the same library compiled with the first version of Fedora, will it be compatible with both release as long as both are f22 and hardware arch is also same?

Answer (score 1):

Forward compatibility is much easier to guarantee than backward compatibility.  If your library depends only on the C runtime (glibc6), then the answer is somewhere between "probably" and "perhaps". If it depends on additional libraries, the likelihood of success is much lower (seriously, no one relies upon backward compatibility of *binary* packages). But if you want to improve the odds, compiling and building the library on the older release helps a lot.